# Office 365 Sharepoint Display Certain Columns for apps

Tags: sharepoint-addin, office-365, task-list

My work has asked me to help with sharepoint, which I am new to.  Basically, I'm trying to display certain columns for the Task app.

Right now, when I go to site contents and click on a task app. It will correctly display the columns I want to show (task status & description).I edited the columns under the Views settings and set it as the default view.

[image: Image of display I want]

However, when I add the task app to a page I created, such as All Tasks page, it does not show the columns I want.  Looks like it goes back to a default view...  See below:

[image: Task app is missing the columns I want]

I guess I'm just trying to figure out what I am over looking.  Is there a way to show the columns I want when I add an app to a created page?  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are seeing differences is that in the first part you are modifying/creating a view for the list.  In the second you are adding in a list view web part to your page.

When you add a list view web part it will go back to the default view.  If you want to change it you can do so by going to the web part properties and selecting your view that you modified in your first step.

[image]

If you start to use a lot of different views of the same list in different places you can bypass the first step you did and just create a view for that specific page, where ever it is you put the list view web part.  Then it won't show up in your actual list as a view too.  To do this you can click on the `Edit the current view` link in the bottom of the circle.

Comment: oh thank you!  Seems like I searched everywhere for that!